# restore data from backup from file in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to restore data which is there in .backup file from /home/somepath/backupfile.backup to mydb.I tried with following psql dbname < infile but it is not restoring data it gives an error says that 'table_name does not exist'.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html), the database must already exist and have rights set to it for the restore to work properly. Did you verify that the template for the database created the framework into which to restore your dumped data? That's what the error sounds like...it can't find the correct table to insert the data.